# Two arrays as keys and values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I do it like this.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:allMyNameObjects forKeys:allMySizeObjects];
```

allMyNameObjects = {a,b,c,d}

allMySizeObjects = {1,2,1,3}

And is dictionary = {a:1,b:2,d:3}

"c" does not appear, because it has same size with "a".

allMySizeObjects objects has in NSNumber

Why it does not work with the same key? And how to make that work? Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You seem to have inversed objects & keys. And Key are *unique* (cf. doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDictionary keys must be unique.

You can reverse keys with objects

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:allMySizeObjects forKeys:allMyNameObjects];
```